# Create basic rounded shape in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

is there a built in class in BOOTSTRAP that can produce a simple blue round box as a place holder for my Copyright, or sidebar title just like from the attached picture? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `list-group` with a single `active` `list-group-item`..

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active text-center">Text here...</li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/YitGAxRo48